# Scraping WEB data using python requests library

Tags: python-requests

**Hello,**

I am trying to access web data using python "requests" library. Below are details of code executed with error message. Appreciate any help in resolving this.

python version: 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (32-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:45:57) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]

**logic:**

```
import requests
response = requests.get("http://dataquestio.github.io/web-scraping-pages/simple.html")
response.text
```

**Traceback**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='dataquestio.github.io', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /web-scraping-pages/simple.html (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x03E676B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))
```

**Thanks,
Gopal.**

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code you have given above, and got the following[image: output:]

---